# What is the difference between useWatch and watch from useForm? [react-hook-form]

Tags: react-hook-form

What is the difference between useWatch and [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) from [useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch)?

Library - react-hook-form

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is clearly a user asking a question who already knows the answer, and offers no better explanation that what can be found easily in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`watch` - This API will trigger re-render at the root of your app or form, consider using a callback or the useWatch api if you are experiencing performance issues.

Comment: Why are you answering the question you asked?

Comment: @dkostreba you can answer your own questions as well, if you have answers...

Comment: Could you provide an example where `watch()` is better? I haven't found any.

Comment: @Rantiev yea, but to write a very basic question, and 2 mins later regurgitate, directly from the docs, almost word for word, the basic description of `useWatch` is a little cheeky :D https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usewatch